# Bash shell option -r

Tags: bash, shell

I am no expert in shell scripts and as I read one of the lines in a bash script, I see this:

```
if [[ ! -r test.json ]]
then
    printf "no test.json here\n" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

What does the line `if [[ ! -r test.json ]]` option do? From the logic, it seems like it checks if the file `test.json` does not exist. I did some research to see what all options are indeed provided in a shell command, but I don't see the `-r` option here: https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/options.html

Comment: That's not a shell option, it's part of a conditional expression.

Comment: Do a _man bash_ and search for the paragraph _CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS_, which shows this file test operator and many other useful ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-r` is one of many possible arguments for the `[`-program and the `[[` bash construct (which is what you're using here).

`-r` checks if the argument that follows it is a file, it exists, and it's readable.

A [bash cheatsheet can be useful](https://devhints.io/bash) for these things while making shell scripts

Comment: I should add, just for clarity: in this case "file" does not necessarily mean "regular file"; it could also be a directory or symbolic link for example.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking in the wrong part of the documentation. It's not a shell option, it's a [conditional expression](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) operator.

> -r *file*
> True if *file* exists and is readable.

The `!` operator inverts the condition, so this tells you if `test.json` doesn't exist or is not readable.